# Python - Canvas scrollbar adjustable with text

Tags: python, canvas, tkinter

Firstly, I'm a french student so I can't speek realy nice English.

I've a problem when a try to make my canvas's scrollbar adjustable depending on quantity of text on my canvas.

I need to have the scrollbar just if my text in the canvas is too big for the screen.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.filedialog import *
from tkinter.messagebox import *
from tkinter.scrolledtext import *

def writeincanvas():
    canvas.insert(canvas_id, 5000, "Hi !" + "\n")

win_crypt = Tk()
win_crypt.title("Canvas adjustable")

canvas = Canvas(win_crypt, width=960, background="white", scrollregion=(0,0,5000,5000))

### here is "scrollregion=(0,0,5000,50000)" but I don't 
### need that because I need auto-adjustable**

scroll = Scrollbar(win_crypt, orient=VERTICAL)
scroll.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
scroll.config(command=canvas.yview)

canvas.config(width=960, yscrollcommand=scroll.set)
canvas.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=BOTH)

canvas_id = canvas.create_text(10, 10, anchor="nw")

Label(win_crypt, text="Clic on the button :").pack(pady=20)
Button(win_crypt, text="Press !", command=writeincanvas).pack(pady=20)

win_crypt.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The canvas method `bbox` returns the coordinates of a *bounding box* for the item or items passed in as an argument. If you pass in the special argument `"all'` it will return the coordinates of the smallest possible rectangle that fits all of the contents. You can use this value for the `scrollregion` attribute after you've added your items to the canvas.

```
def writeincanvas():
    canvas.insert(canvas_id, 5000, "Hi !" + "\n")
    canvas.configure(scrollregion=canvas.bbox("all"))
```

Comment: Nice thanks, it works perfectly. And thanks for quoting my text because I don't realy no how to make that correctly.

Comment: But you know how it possible to select the text with the mouse ?

Comment: @Quentium: that's completely unrelated to this question. If you have another question, click the "Ask Question" button.